# Xamarin Forms: How to Read Data from Json File from the Phonestorage of my android smartphone

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, mobile

im trying to read Data From A Json File that is in the Storage of the Phone that uses the App. How can I Do that ?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What did you try already? Please share some code that shows your affords so far and where *specifically* you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Additional information can be found in [File Handling in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows):

```
// get file name
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "YourJsonFile.json");
// read file
string json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

// deserialize/parse json
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
// or
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
```

The above assumes use of `Newtonsoft.Json`, however, similar can be achieved using `System.Text.Json`.